# My @Test method in Selenium is running two times

Tags: java, testng

```
/*I have written a @Test method in Selenium which is running twice but i want it to run only once. Basically, i have written @DataProvider method which is returning 2 dimensional array to same @Test method and my @DataProvider is calling another method in other class which also returns a 2 dimensional array. */

//Below is the code from other class i.e., ExcelUtil


package util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtil {

//Fetching data from excel
public static Object[][] fetchDataFromExcel(String filePath, String sheetName, String methodname){

        Map<Object, Object> datamap= new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        Object[][] obj = null;
        try{

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
            XSSFRow rw = sh.getRow(0);

            int totalRows = sh.getLastRowNum();
            int cellNum = rw.getLastCellNum();
            obj = new Object[totalRows+1][1];

                for(int i=0;i<totalRows;i++) {                              

                    XSSFRow tstrw = sh.getRow(i);
                    String txt = tstrw.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

                    if(txt.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(methodname.trim())) {

                        datamap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

                        for(int j=0;j<cellNum-1;j++) {

                        datamap.put(rw.getCell(j+1).getStringCellValue(),
                        sh.getRow(i).getCell(j+1).getStringCellValue());

                        }   
                        obj[i][0] = datamap;
                        //printing two dimensional array 
                        System.out.println("obj["+i+"][0] = " + obj[i][0]);
                        //break;    


                    }

                }

            wb.close();

        }catch(Exception fetchDataFromExcel) {

            fetchDataFromExcel.printStackTrace();

        }

        return obj;

    }

}

//Below is my Test class which consists of @DataProvider and @Test

package com.qa.tests;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import util.ExcelUtil;
import util.LogInPageObject;

public class MyLogoTest {

    Method[] methods = MyLogoTest.class.getMethods();

    WebDriver driver;

    @DataProvider(name = "readDataFromExcel")
    public Object[][] dataFromExcel(Method method) {
        Object[][] fetchDataFromExcel = null;

        try {

            String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
             "\\src\\test\\resources\\TestData.xlsx";
            //calling fetchDataFromExcel for ExcelUtil class
            fetchDataFromExcel = ExcelUtil.fetchDataFromExcel(filePath, "Login", method.getName());

        } catch (Exception dataFromExcel) {

            dataFromExcel.printStackTrace();

        }

        return fetchDataFromExcel;

    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void invokeBrowser() {

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    }
    //This method below is running two times but i want it should run only once
    @Test(dataProvider="readDataFromExcel")
    public void logIn(Map<String, String> data) {

        try {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(LogInPageObject.signInXpath)).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);

        }catch(Exception logIn) {

            logIn.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {

        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Output in the Console after running

```
PASSED: logIn(null)
PASSED: logIn({Username=kumar7000@gmail.com, Password=123456})

===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

And below is the data in my excel

[image]

Can anyone help me with this, I don't want `"PASSED: logIn(null)"` in my output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
Object[][] obj = null;
int totalRows = sh.getLastRowNum();
obj = new Object[totalRows+1][1];
```

`totalRows` is 1, when you initialize `obj` you are giving it 2 rows. The first row contains the data from the file, but the second row remains `null` (the initial value).

```
@Test(dataProvider="readDataFromExcel")
```

See two values, `Map` with values and `null`, so two tests are being created

```
logIn({Username=kumar7000@gmail.com, Password=123456})
// and
logIn(null)
```

Just fix the array initialization

```
obj = new Object[totalRows][1];
```

Comment: i fix the array initialization but issue remains the same and also i am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 along with PASSED: logIn(null).

Comment: @MiteshKumar You probably have extra/empty lines in the excel that doesn't match the `if` in `fetchDataFromExcel`.

Comment: no problem is with DataProvider. It is sending 2 dimensional array with values [0,0] which is null and value [1,0] which has datamap and because of these 2 values my test case is running 2 times, that's why first logIn is null and 2nd times it passes correctly. I want my Test to run 1 time only.

Comment: @MiteshKumar that's what I wrote in my answer and the null in [0,0] is what causing the test to run with null value.